# Is there an option to add a header and trailer record using snowflake copy command?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to generate a file in GCP from snowflake table.
My requirement is as below for the file to look like:

Output file:

1. Records count
2. Table Data with column Names
3. Trailer records which can have some other stats about the table

Sample output file should look like below:

```
Total Number of records
-----------------------
200

Name  Age  Department
----------------------
XX    40       ABC

Number of records belonging to department ABC
---------------------------------------------
1
```

Is this doable in a single copy into command? Please suggest options in order to achieve the above scenario.
Thanks

I tried this copy command.

```
copy into @stage from (select cast(count() as character) as count_rec from <TABLE> 
union all 
select FIRST_NM AS "FIRST_NAME" from <TABLE> 
union all 
select cast(count() as character) as count_rec from <TABLE>) header=TRUE;
```

But the problem is only the header from 1st sql (count_rec) is displayed in output. I would need the column names also to be displayed from 2nd sql. And the  count_rec header from 3rs sql.

this is what it looks like now:

[image]

Are there any options to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? The short answer is no, this is clearly can not be done in one copy command but there can be workarounds. If you tried any attempts add them to your question.

Comment: No not in a single Copy command, you will have to write a separate Procedure which you will call after the Copy is sucessful.

Comment: Thanks for responses. I tried this copy command.   copy into @stage from 
  (select cast(count(*) as character) as count_rec from <TABLE>
   union all
    select FIRST_NM AS "FIRST_NAME" from <TABLE>
   union all
    select cast(count(*) as character) as count_rec from <TABLE>)
  header=TRUE;                                                                                                                    But the problem is only the header from 1st sql (count_rec) is displayed in output. I would need the column names also to be displayed from 2nd sql. Are there any options to do this?